# Spring batch 5 not launch specific job in multijob configuration spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, service, spring-batch

I have created a Spring Batch 5 with spring boot 3.2.3, in this batch we have several jobs, we injected service interface annotated with @

main class

```
    package com.telr.reconciliation;


import com.telr.reconciliation.service.CustomerAdviceService;
import com.telr.reconciliation.service.TelrPgrComparisonService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import java.io.IOException;

    @Configuration
    @Slf4j
    public class ReconciliationConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {
    
        CustomerAdviceService customerAdviceService;
    
        TelrPgrComparisonService telrPgrComparisonService;
    
        public ReconciliationConfiguration(CustomerAdviceService customerAdviceService, TelrPgrComparisonService telrPgrComparisonService) {
            this.customerAdviceService = customerAdviceService;
            this.telrPgrComparisonService = telrPgrComparisonService;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Job reconciliationStep1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws IOException {
            return new JobBuilder("reconciliation", jobRepository)
                    .start(customerAdviceServiceStep(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Job reconciliationStep3(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
            return new JobBuilder("finalComparison", jobRepository)
                    .start(telrPgrComparisonServiceStep(jobRepository, transactionManager))
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Step customerAdviceServiceStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
            return new StepBuilder("customeradviceservice", jobRepository)
                    .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        log.info("CustomerAdviceService has started...");
                        customerAdviceService.aggregate();
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }, transactionManager)
                    .build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Step telrPgrComparisonServiceStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
            return new StepBuilder("telrpgrcomparison", jobRepository)
                    .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        log.info("Job telrPgrComparisonService has started...");
                        telrPgrComparisonService.process();
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }, transactionManager)
                    .build();
        }
    }
```

application.properties
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

i tried to launch with command
java -jar reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.telr.reconciliation.ReconciliationConfiguration reconciliation
or
java -jar reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dspring.batch.job.name=finalComparison or even java -jar reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.batch.job.name=finalComparison

in any case i have thoses logs and job is not launched

```
2024-03-06T09:27:11.273+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : Starting ReconciliationApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 21.0.2 with PID 21649 (/home/cyril/Desktop/dev/projects/reconciliation/target/reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by cyril in /home/cyril/Desktop/dev/projects/reconciliation/target)
2024-03-06T09:27:11.274+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-06T09:27:11.700+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'customerAdviceServiceImpl' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.service.impl.CustomerAdviceServiceImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.773+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'telrPgrComparisonServiceImpl' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.service.impl.TelrPgrComparisonServiceImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.776+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'reconciliationConfiguration' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.ReconciliationConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.778+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.844+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-06T09:27:12.021+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2024-03-06T09:27:12.021+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@476e8796
2024-03-06T09:27:12.022+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-06T09:27:12.187+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : Started ReconciliationApplication in 1.153 seconds (process running for 1.512)
2024-03-06T09:27:12.192+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-03-06T09:27:12.197+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

2024-03-06T09:27:11.273+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : Starting ReconciliationApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 21.0.2 with PID 21649 (/home/cyril/Desktop/dev/projects/reconciliation/target/reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by cyril in /home/cyril/Desktop/dev/projects/reconciliation/target)
2024-03-06T09:27:11.274+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-06T09:27:11.700+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'customerAdviceServiceImpl' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.service.impl.CustomerAdviceServiceImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.773+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'telrPgrComparisonServiceImpl' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.service.impl.TelrPgrComparisonServiceImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.776+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'reconciliationConfiguration' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.ReconciliationConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.778+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.844+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-06T09:27:12.021+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2024-03-06T09:27:12.021+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@476e8796
2024-03-06T09:27:12.022+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-06T09:27:12.187+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : Started ReconciliationApplication in 1.153 seconds (process running for 1.512)
2024-03-06T09:27:12.192+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-03-06T09:27:12.197+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.273+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : Starting ReconciliationApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 21.0.2 with PID 21649 (/home/cyril/Desktop/dev/projects/reconciliation/target/reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by cyril in /home/cyril/Desktop/dev/projects/reconciliation/target)
2024-03-06T09:27:11.274+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-06T09:27:11.700+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'customerAdviceServiceImpl' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.service.impl.CustomerAdviceServiceImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.773+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'telrPgrComparisonServiceImpl' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.service.impl.TelrPgrComparisonServiceImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.776+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'reconciliationConfiguration' of type [com.telr.reconciliation.ReconciliationConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.778+04:00  WARN 21649 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
2024-03-06T09:27:11.844+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-06T09:27:12.021+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2024-03-06T09:27:12.021+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@476e8796
2024-03-06T09:27:12.022+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-06T09:27:12.187+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [           main] c.t.r.ReconciliationApplication          : Started ReconciliationApplication in 1.153 seconds (process running for 1.512)
2024-03-06T09:27:12.192+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-03-06T09:27:12.197+04:00  INFO 21649 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

i checked Spring batch documentation but i dont see about this topic, injecting service in a single job is working, if i do not set the sen enable batch in propeties job work but have issue because ask to specify job name

Comment: Use `--spring.batch.job.name` the  `-D` arguments should be placed directly after `java` not as a command argument. So either do `java -Dspring.batch.job.name=finalComparison -jar reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` or `java -jar reconciliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.batch.job.name=finalComparison`. In both cases you are running you basically aren't specifying any job to run.

Comment: already tested but in combinaison as spring.batch.job.enabled=false this is not working, if you comment this line the configuration are working and this value is mandatory for mvn install or test or it ask to give espacially a job to tun, that is incorrect

Comment: Well yeah as that disables the launching of a batch job.

Comment: it prevent to launch any batch on launch, you have to provide the job to launch... but not working, so how to concil, test, mvn install with multiple job in spring batch

Comment: No it doesn't. It disables the launching of the job in its totallity. When there are multiple jobs you will need to specify which one. If you set that property to false it will not register the `JobLauncherApplicationRunner` which is what uses the `spring.batch.job.name` property to select the job. Without it it doesn't do anything.

Comment: ok so how to launch correclty tests, mvn install, and choose the job to launch on startup ? i mean thos config has a role, if it to deactivate all stuff, write nothig is the same ... and xwhat the purpose of it ? thant you

Comment: Enable it and provide the configuration, you have multiple jobs so nothing willhappen. Unless you messed up your configuration or test. Nonetheless you need to have that enabled to launch the job with the parameter or write your own mechanism.